# npm scripts running with parameters in VS Code

Tags: terminal, environment-variables

I have been given a functioning project that is installed on a remote server.
When I connect to it and execute commands they have the following view
Example:

```
INTERVAL="2021-08-30T22:00:00.797Z/2021-08-31T21:59:59Z" getA=false  npm 
start
```

If i understand correctly,everything that is coming before npm start is referred to as process environment variables. But i a not 100 percent sure

i cloned the project to my machine so that i could do the upgrades and launch it without connecting to the server.
When i try to run it through the terminal of visual studio, i Get Nada, error messages that

```
is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet
```

And if I simply run **npm start** and put all these extra parameters after, they are not taken into account

Where should I read on this and why should that be an issue at all?

Basically my question is , how can I run the code from visual studio code on my PC the same way it is launched from the server?
Should I somehow add these process.env somewhere?

Comment: Could you please re-phrase? Your question is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: @SirStopIt is it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simpler than I have anticipated.

You don't have to add the variable to path or anything weird of that sort

All that there is to be done:

```
INTERVAL="2021-08-30T22:00:00.797Z/2021-08-31T21:59:59Z" getA=false  npm 
start
```

should be splitted in 3 commands that are to be passed as such:

```
$env:INTERVAL="2021-08-30T22:00:00.797Z/2021-08-31T21:59:59Z"
```

```
$env:getA=false
```

```
npm start
```

voila.